# Ruby on Rails - how to cache the result of a response of an API service?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, caching

I have a `RoR 3.2.3` web site. It calls a web service of `flickr.com` to get the list of my photos. But it  doesn't really matter.

The bottom line is, that it does a request each time -- each time a visitor comes to my web site it calls a web service of `flickr.com` to get the list of the photos.  Obviously I'd like to cache the respose of `flickr` for about 5 hours. As far as I'm concerned it would be enough.

So how can I do it? What is the good or best way to it or just the general approach? Maybe you have a link how to make it?

P.S. I use the **free tariff** plan of `heroku.com` with 5Mb that supports `PostgreSQL` database. However if it's necessary I could migrate to other hoster.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Memcached is a good option to start with. Heroku has [it built-in for free](https://addons.heroku.com/memcache) (5mb). Setup guide can be found [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/memcache#using_memcache_from_ruby)

```
$ heroku addons:add memcache
$ vim Gemfile
  gem 'dalli'
$ vim config/environments/production.rb
  config.cache_store = :dalli_store
$ heroku console
  Rails.cache.stats
```

Then you can wrap your expensive API request into Rails.cache block, see the code below:

```
class Flickr
  def self.cached_request
    Rails.cache.fetch "photos", :expires_in => 5.minutes do
      flickr.photos.getRecent
    end
  end
end
```

Then to get use the cache, just run

```
Flickr.cached_request
```

It will fire API request and cache them for 5 minutes.

Comment: Not completely. Do you suggest me to use the expire time of 5 minutes? I'm going to use about 5-10 hours for this, would it be good? Just your opinion.

Comment: @AlexMaslakov it depends on server capacity and frequency how often pictures change. 5 minutes appropriates to newsfeed and data that always change, but 5-10 hours should be ok for the a photostream

Comment: Heroku no longer supports the memcache add-on. [This tweet](https://twitter.com/HerokuAddons/status/306108405670612993) from [@HerokuAddons](https://twitter.com/HerokuAddons) suggests using [MemCachier](https://addons.heroku.com/memcachier) instead. It's a drop-in replacement with 5 times the free space. To add MemCachier, run `heroku addons:add memcachier:dev`.

Answer (score 2):

it depends on how you want your cache to work. usually, you are good with a memcached or redis store. both runs on heroku.

have a look at the guides for caching http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html